# Requiring a Ruby module in Rails console & controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require

I need the Ruby module `FileUtils` to handle some operations with files.

I want to test that this require will work correctly in my controller. So I tried this in my console but got `false` as a result (this works fine when I'm not in a Rails console but just a plain Ruby console):

1. Go to the root directory of my project
2. `$ rails c` to open my console
3. `> require 'fileutils'` returns `false`.

What is the correct way to require a module via rails console? Why would this return false?

I'm assuming in my controller I can just do something like this, correct?

```
def create
  require 'fileutils'
  # my code that uses fileutils.
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `false` response from `require` means that the module is already loaded.  You should be good to go without requiring this in your controller.  See docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require

Comment: Thanks steakchaser - do you know where the docs on best practices for requiring other modules in *Rails* are? I've been googling but can only fine Ruby docs.

Comment: It's a good question.  I would probably go with an initializer if you want everything to have access to a modules class methods.  Less broadly, you can require in various base classes (i.e. ApplicationController).  Or, it can also be required as a one off to some service / concern that has a very contained need for another lib (this is usually what ends up happening for me).

Answer (score 5):

It is most likely already required by default. Just type `FileUtils` in the console, it should respond

```
 # => FileUtils
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning `false` from `require` means that it's already loaded.

Try this from the console:

```
FileUtils.pwd
# => "/present/working/directory
```