# require 'date' => false testing Date, DateTime etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, console

I'm trying to test out some Date, DateTime and Time related code in `rails console`. Every time I try to `require 'date'` in the console it returns `false`.

What could be causing this to happen? How do I overcome this obstacle if it is one?

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022569/requiring-a-ruby-module-in-rails-console-controller      tl:dr: if require returns 'false', then it's already loaded.

Comment: That's interesting, then alternatively what would 'true' me if I 'require date'?

Comment: It means it wasn't loaded before, but is now.

Comment: Simple enough, thanks!